# High lock_manager wait event

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-11

I'm currently facing an issue with some selects by primary key. The selects sometimes take more than 10 seconds to return the row. I've analyzed the execution plan and verified that it's ok.

I started to look the queries running on the database with the following select:

```
select wait_event_type, wait_event, count(1)
from pg_stat_activity
where state <> ‘idle’
and state is not null
group by wait_event_type, wait_event
order by count(1) desc;
```

Then I saw a lot of sessions waiting in lock_manager:
[wait_event_type / wait_event by count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgR65.png)

Then, I went to the pg_locks to see what type of lock was causing the issue: [locks by mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfuQV.png)
The most common lock mode was *AccessShareLock*.
I also saw the average lock by pid, and it was about 3000. Most of the locks are in partitioned tables (my select is going through the main table, and the AccessShareLock's are in all partitions and partition indexes).
I increased the max_locks_per_transaction from 128 to 5120, but had no improvements.

Another thing that I do, was run *perf top* and see what was the "hot function": hash_search_with_hash_value. [perf top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlREC.png)

The server machine is with a low cpu usage: 20%.

Do you have any solution for this? Do you need some more information?

Comment: Perhaps you have too many partitions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have 4 tables with 900 partitions each. Each partition have 4 indexes. I don't know, but how much is too much?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `count(1)` is actually slower than `count(*)`

Comment: I am guessing at this stage. 900 partitions sounds OK. But given that you have over 600000 AccessShare locks, my next guess is that you have too many concurrent database sessions trying to select from these tables simultaneously. Do things improve if you reduce the connection pool size?

Comment: @jjanes The server has an Intel Xeon Gold 6146 (12 cores, 24 threads) with 96GB.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried to reduce the connections to 100. The Access Share locks drop to around 200000, but I still seeing lock_manager wait event. I'm suspecting of the hash_search_with_hash_value method in PostgreSQL. I think that are a lot of collisions (600000 locks in 5120 bucket == 117 collisions per bucket). The implentation uses a linked list for the collisions. Would it be better if it was a binary tree? With a linked list I have to check 117 values, with a binary tree only 7 values.

Comment: Complicated. You should try to catch a process while it is waiting for `lock_manager` and [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend). Another approach is to use `perf` to get a call graph and figure out where the many hash table lookups come from (could be a join too). Finally, try to reduce the number of connections even more and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'll get the stack trace. I can't reduce the number of connections because my application won't keep up with the desired throughput. As soon as I have the stack trace, I'll post here. Thanks

Comment: "I can't reduce the number of connections because my application won't keep up with the desired throughput"  Isn't already not keeping up?

Comment: In my experience "threads" are useless for database workloads and only real cores count.  Having > 200 processes demanding attention from 12 CPU at the same time is not going to cause good things to happen.

Comment: Why do you think there are 5120 buckets?  Are you referring to a particular part of the source code here?

Comment: @jjanes Actually, the app is keeping up (but soon will not). I was thinking the locks table was with 5120 buckets (max_locks_per_transaction), but analizing the source code, it's max_locks_per_transaction * max_connections. In my case: 5120 * 2048 = 10 millions. I did what Laurenz suggested and the function get_tab_stat_entry is causing slow down (it's calling the function hash_search_with_hash_value in a table with a bucket of 100 (defined in pgstat.c). I'm enabling HASH_STATISTICS and seeing a lot of collision: destroy: total accesses 5986886 total collisions 2227407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be to upgrade from v11 to (at least) v12.  Partitioning got much more efficient, in turns of locking for single-partition selects, in that version.

Comment: I saw the release notes. I'm planning the upgrade, but I have to test the application. I'm trying to "configure" first while I'm planning the upgrade. I'll run my tests against the v12 and see the results!

Comment: I did the test agains the v12, I didn't see any lock_manager wait event! Thanks